# Independence of two sequences of 1's and 0's.

Tags: probability

Given a family $F_n$ that has $n \ge 2$ children, consider the two statements:

1. A: $F_n$ has 0 or 1 girl
2. B: $F_n$ has both boy(s) and girl(s).

Also assume boys and girls are equally likely to be born.

(1) I would like to check if A and B are independent. My argument is no since the statement:

$$P(A) = P(A|B)$$ is false. Let call $A_0$ the event that $F_n$ has 0 girl and $A_1$ the even that $F_n$ has one girl. Then

$$P(A) = P(A_0) + P(A_1)$$ while

$$P(A|B) = P(A_0|B) + P(A_1|B) = 0 + P(A_1|B)$$ and we see $P(A) \ge P(A|B)$. If this line of thinking is flawed please let me know.

**EDIT**
Alternatively, $P(A_1|B) = P(A_1) + P(A_0)$ since if we know the family has boys and girls, then the probability of $A_1$ increases by exactly the probability that there are no girls. Then

$$P(A|B) = P(A_1) + P(A_0) = P(A).$$ And they are independent.

(2) Does the answer depend on $n$? This one is trickier to me because on the one hand, I would think no matter how large the $n$, $P(A_0) \ne 0$. On the other hand,is $n$ is infinity, as the wording $n \ge 2$ suggests, then $A_0$ correspond to the binary expansion of $0$, that is $.0000\ldots$. And the probability of any countable set is $0$. So $P(A) = P(A_0) + P(A_1) = P(A_1)$. And if $P(A_1) = P(A_1|B)$ (correct assumption?), then we have $P(A) = P(A|B)$, so they are independent.

Comment: "and we see $P(A) \ge P(A|B)$". How do we see that exactly? Note that $P(A_{1}|B)$ could be higher than $P(A_{1})$ and in general could be equal to $P(A)$, right?

Comment: You're right, I am not sure how to think about $P(A_1|B)$ relative to $P(A_1)$. I suppose given the information that of $B$, then $P(A_1)$ increases by exactly $P(A_0)$. So we have $P(A|B) = P(A_0|B) + (P(A_1) + P(A_0)) = P(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n=2$, clearly $B\subseteq A$, as if $B$ holds then the family must have exactly one daughter (it cannot have 2), and thus $A$ holds. So $\Pr[A \cap B] = \Pr[B]$, and $A$ and $B$ are not independent (as $\Pr[A] \neq 1$).

If $n>2$, however, it is not that obvious, since (abusing notations to denote the number of girls and boys, and assuming each child is independent from the others) $$\Pr[A \cap B] = \Pr[(1,n-1)] = \binom{n}{n-1}\frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{n}{2^{n}}$$
while 
$\Pr[A] = \Pr[(0,n)] + \Pr[(1,n-1)] = \frac{1}{2^{n}}+ \frac{n}{2^{n}}$, $\Pr[B] = 1-(\Pr[(0,n)] + \Pr[(n,0)]) = 1-\frac{2}{2^{n}} = 1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$. The events are dependent, as the equality $\Pr[A]\Pr[B] = \Pr[A \cap B]$ is only verified when
$$
\left( \frac{n}{2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right)\left( 1-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\right) = \frac{n}{2^{n}}
$$
i.e. when $n = 2^{n-1}-1$. The only integer solution is $n=3$.

---

**Summary:** the events are independent for $n=3$, and dependent for all other $n \geq 2$.

Comment: in the sentence 'and assuming each child is dependent from the others', did you meant to say independent?

Comment: Yes, sorry -- typos.

Comment: @chibro2: corrected the mistakes (in the probability of $A\cap B$ and $A$).

Comment: Nope: to have 1 girl and $n-1$ boys, you avec $\binom{n}{n-1}=n$ different configurations (which of the $n$ children the boys are), and then a probability $1/2^n$ to achieve this particular configuration.

Comment: yeah sorry right after I posted the comment I saw my mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For $n=3$, I think the events $A_3$ and $B_3$ are independent:

$P(A_3)=\frac12$;

$P(B_3)=\frac34$:

$P(A_3\cap B_3)=\frac38=P(A_3)\cdot P(B_3)$ .  For this last one, $A_3\cap B_3$ occurs if you have one girl and two boys.